# Programmatically setting instance name with the OpenStack Nova API

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud, openstack

I have resigned myself to the fact that many of the features that EC2 users are accustomed to (in particular, tagging) do not exist in OpenStack. There is, however, one piece of functionality whose absence is driving me crazy.

Although OpenStack doesn't have full support for instance tags (like EC2 does), it **does** have the notion of an instance name. This name is exposed by the Web UI, which even allows you to set it:

[image: Instance Name in the instance list]

[image: Editing the Instance Name]

This name is also exposed through the `nova list` command line utility.

However (and this is my problem) this field is *not* exposed through the `nova-ec2` API layer. The cleanest way for them to integrate this with existing EC2 platform tools would be to simulate an instance Tag with name "Name", but they don't do this. What's more, I can't figure out which Nova API endpoint I can use to read and write the name (it doesn't seem to be documented on the [API reference](http://api.openstack.org/)); but of course it must be somehow possible since the web client and `nova-client` can both somehow do it.

At the moment, I'm forced to change it manually from the website every time I launch a new instance. (I can't do it during instance creation because I use the `nova-ec2` API, not the `nova` command line client).

My question is:

1. Is there a way to read/write the instance name through the EC2 API layer?
2. Failing that, what is the REST endpoint to set it programmatically?
3. **(BONUS)**: What is Nova's progress on supporting general instance tagging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Python `novaclient.v1_1` package has a method on the `server` object:

```python
def update(self, server, name=None):
    """
    Update the name or the password for a server.

    :param server: The :class:`Server` (or its ID) to update.
    :param name: Update the server's name.
    """
    if name is None:
        return

    body = {
        "server": {
            "name": name,
        },
    }

    self._update("/servers/%s" % base.getid(server), body)
```

This indicates that you can update the name of a server by POST-ing
the following JSON to `http://nova-api:port/v2.0/servers/{server-id}`:

```js
{
  "server": {
      "name": "new_name"
  }
}
```

Of course, all of the usual authentication headers (namely `X-Auth-Token`
from your Keystone server) are still required, so it is probably easier to
use a client library for whatever language you prefer to manage all that.

Comment: Thanks, this worked (I ended up just going with Python `novaclient`. So I now have two different client libraries to access the same API. Oh, well!)

Comment: To answer your 3rd question, it has been added to the bug wishlist. https://bugs.launchpad.net/nova/+bug/770070

Comment: @EverettToews: Thanks; however, considering that this was filed well over a year ago, and nothing at all seems to have happened, I'm not holding my breath :)